# How to write a SQL Query to get the following ...

Tags: sql

I think this is a simple SQL query problem, but I am just not familiar enough with the different SQL join types to get the best solution to this problem.

I have a system that manages various `items` and the `owners` of those items. A `user` of the system has access to view all information about the items and the owners of such items if the user has permissions to view that owner. My schema looks like:

```
Users:
| UserId |

Items:
| ItemId | OwnerId | Name | Age |

Owners:
| OwnerId | FirstName | LastName | State |

OwnerPermissions:
| UserId | OwnerId |
```

It is possible that an Item does not have an owner -- then OwnerId is NULL for that row in the Items table.

So if an entry exists for UserId=0 and OwnerId=0 and OwnerId=1 in `OwnerPermissions` then UserId=0 can view all the item information owned by OwnerId 0 and 1.

I want to write a query that given a userId, it returns all Item and Owner information for the owners the user has permissions to see, *and also shows all items that don't have owners*

The query:

```
select Items.*, Owners.* 
from Items
inner join Owners on Items.OwnerId = Owners.OwnerId
inner join OwnerPermissions on OwnerPermissions.OwnerId = Owners.OwnerId
where OwnerPermissions.UserId = $userId
```

Gets me all the Item information that are owned by people I have permission to see, but it misses the Items that are not owned by anyone (OwnerId is NULL).

What is the best way to write this query? I use SQL Server, but I prefer an answer that doesn't rely on it (but would be interested if there is a neat trick SQL Server can do)

Comment: "ANSI standard SQL specifies four types of JOINs: INNER, OUTER, LEFT, and RIGHT" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL\)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to a `LEFT JOIN` and every item is shown, with `NULL` if it has no owner.

```
select Items.*, Owners.* 
from Items
left join Owners on Items.OwnerId = Owners.OwnerId
left join OwnerPermissions on OwnerPermissions.OwnerId = Owners.OwnerId
where OwnerPermissions.UserId = $userId
```